# What can be a regular expression to match number followed by any number of *

Tags: python, regex

I have a data in the sqlite database. I need to match cell value which follow these rules --

- Starting or ending with a given number.
- There can be any number of * after a given number.
- Number can appear anywhere in the larger string of numbers where numbers are separated by comma.

```
1. 355
2. 35,36
3. 35,36,355
4. 45,35***,355
5. 35
6. 35*
7. 45,35*
8. 50
9. 45,36
10. 151943
11. 5,355*,5
12. 3,5
13. 3, 35**, 5
```

Here output should be line number 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 13.

What should be the ideal regular expression for this.

`import re

def match(expr, item):
    x = re.match(expr, item)
    if x is not None:
        return True
items=['355','35,36','35,36,355','45,35***,355','35','35*','45,35*','50','45,36','151943','5,355*,5','3,5','3500,57','351,35**,4']

for item in items:
  if match('.*,?(35)\**,?.*', item):
     print item`

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do? or the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: What language is this in? If you want to match the specific number followed by any number of asterisks, then `/35\**(,|$)/` will do it.

Comment: Is this [tag:qt]? Please tag the question if so.

Comment: The regex you're using reduces to `.*35.*` which matches any line with `35` in it.

Answer (score 0):

What if we don't have regular expressions available?

```
# Recognize valid items
def valid(item):
    VALUE = "35"
    values = item.replace("*", "").split(",")
    return VALUE in values

# Display valid items
for item in items:
    if valid(item):
         print item
```

Simply, we remove all asterisks, we create a list of individual values, and we check whether the expected value is present there.